# How can I merge two pandas dataframes without a common column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have a Pandas dataframe in which there is a column called "employees", another "entry time", and another "exit time".

In these columns, the name of an employee, their entry time, and their exit time are respectively recorded.

There is also another Pandas dataframe called "incidents", in which there are two columns, "incident" and "incident time".

How can I see which incidents have occurred for each employee?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your two inputs and the matching expected output, the question is currently unclear. This looks like a merge between start/end.